# How do I use a glob with parentheses in Zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh

This:

```
cp ./hb_(lys|gln|thr|glu|ace|nhe)*_aacH*.ptraj ./
```

Works just as intended when executed in the terminal. However, putting the same line in an executable script does not work as I receive a

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('\
```

I tried escaping `\`, does not solve the problem. For bash there seems to be some thing you need to do with `extglob`though I can't find any similar suggestions for zsh.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: The glob syntax you're using is zsh-only, and that looks like a bash error message. Exactly how are you running this script, and what shebang does it have (if any)? Also, do you want use bash for it (in which case you'd need to enable `extglob` and then use different syntax), or run it in zsh and stick with the current syntax?

Comment: Indeed, forgetting to specify a shebang and naively assuming zsh was the cause of the problem. When macOS made the switch to zsh as the default shell I obviously made some unfounded assumptions. Thank you, works just fine when specifying zsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with shell options. Rather, it depends on what [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) you have in your executable file.

When you run a script as an executable (instead of `source`-ing it or running it as a function), it runs in a separate sub-shell and not in your top-level shell. A sub-shell inherits its parent's environment (that is, `export`ed parameters), but not any shell options. Instead, the shebang dictates which shell it runs in and with which options.

If the shebang is `#!/bin/zsh`, it will start a Zsh sub-shell with default options, then read commands from `/etc/zshenv` and `$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv`, and then from your script.

Likewise, if the shebang is `#!/bin/bash`, your script will actually run in Bash, and not in Zsh.

Finally, if the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`, it depends on your OS. On macOS, there is a symlink `/private/var/select/sh` that points to the shell executable to use when the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`. (Type `man 1 sh` for more info.) By default, **that shell is Bash,** and not Zsh, *even if you have changed your login shell to Zsh.* The only way to change it is to change that symlink.

But even if you make `/private/var/select/sh` point to the Zsh executable, if you run your script with a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, Zsh will not run in "native mode". Instead, it will run in `sh` emulation mode, which toggles a number of options that are [significantly different from the Zsh defaults](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html).

Parentheses are [basic glob syntax in Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation). However, they are not in Bash. So, my guess is, your script is actually running in Bash, because of the shebang.

---

So, anyway, long story short: Save yourself the trouble and don't run your script as an executable. Rather, what is usually the most convenient in Zsh, is to add your script's parent dir to your `$fpath` and then `autoload` your script [as a function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Functions).

Comment: Parentheses are not basic glob syntax, they're a zsh-only extension.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. Then the OP is definitely not running the script in Zsh.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, although I have another addition: the shebang is ignored if you specify an interpreter when running the script. That is, if you run the script with `bash scriptname`, it runs in bash, no matter what the shebang says it should run in. Similarly, `zsh scriptname` will run it in zsh, and `sh scriptname` will use whatever `sh` happens to be on your system. For this reason, I recommend *not* specifying an interpreter when you run a script -- either put it in a directory in your `PATH` and just use its name, or just run it with `/path/to/scriptname` (or `./scriptname` for the current dir).

Comment: I'll just say thank you to all of you and the very informative answer! Yes, I was basing  decision on bad assumptions. I was looking to run in zsh but missed including the shebang. Did not know that this meant using bash/sh or that sh still refers to bash rather then the default zsh. Thanks to all for great information.